# How can I count clockwise vs counterclockwise cycles in a series of (modular) integers?

Tags: combinatorics, markov-chains, pattern-recognition, biology

I'm working with a Markov process that has a state and transition diagram like in the picture:

[image: six-state cyclical reversible markov chain]

The transition probabilities are not listed, but they are always positive, but not necessarily equal.  When I simulate my system, I'll get a random sequence of states like this:
$$\{1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6...\}$$

Say my original state is $1$.  Clearly if I start at $1$, I can wind up back at $1$, but for my purposes, *how* I do so matters.

I'm modeling a biological process, so if I make a cycle $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,1\}$ clockwise, I turn energy into a biomolecule, while if I go counterclockwise: $\{1,6,5,4,3,2,1\}$, I do the opposite.  If I just go $\{1,2,3,2,1\}$ I get nothing.

Given a long sequence of states, I want to know the net number of clockwise cycles I make: $$N_{net} = N_{clockwise} - N_{counterclockwise}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Summing the differences and dividing by 6 should give you $N_{net}$, as long as you make a special case for 6->1 as +1 and 1->6 as -1.

Comment: What's wrong with focussing on any pair of neighbours, say $(1,2)$, and counting just the transitions between them, with a sign for the direction of the transition. (I'm supposing is suffices to know $N_{\rm net}$ up to a unit; if not the final point reached tells you how much of an incomplete cycle is left.)

Comment: I think this is right on – look at the differences, with the special cases 1->6 = -1 & 6->1 = 1, and then the sum of differences divided by six seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking you have $6$ states, pretend you have infinitely many states and that from state $k$ you can either go to $k+1$ or $k-1$.

Then your final state is $k \mod 6$ and $N_{net} = \lfloor k/6 \rfloor$.

EDIT: The above formula for $N_{net}$ does not work for $k < 0$. If $k < 0$, $N_{net} = \lceil k/6 \rceil$.

Comment: that's definitely a way to think about it, but i'd like to keep may state-space bounded.  I think this idea and the comments to my question are getting at the same idea.